# plugin dakepicker android phonegap

Tags: javascript, plugins, cordova, datepicker

I am trying to use datepicker phonegap-plugin-android([datepickerPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker)). It worked, but I have problem when I click on the textbox from the 2nd onwards, datepicker show 2 times.

```
$  function callDatePicker()
    {
        $('.nativedatepicker').mousedown(function(event) {
            var currentField = $(this);
            var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();
            if(typeof myNewDate === "number"){ myNewDate = new Date (myNewDate); }
            // Same handling for iPhone and Android
            window.plugins.datePicker.show({
                date : myNewDate,
                mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
                allowOldDates : true
            }, function(returnDate) {
                var array = returnDate.split("/");
                var day = array[2], month = array[1];
                if (day <= 9)
                    day = "0" + day;
                if (month <= 9)
                    month = "0" + month;
                currentField.val(day + "/" + month + "/" + array[0]);
                currentField.blur();
        });
```

Comment: Even I have the same issue, but for me it is working on Nexus but not on samsung devices! Which device are you using?

Comment: Do you know this cause ? I use Fujitsu f02e devices.I hope early overcoming!!!!